# R function doesn't return value

Tags: r, function

I'm working on a Kaggle Kernel relating to FIFA 19 data(https://www.kaggle.com/karangadiya/fifa19) and trying to create a function which adds up numbers in a column. 
The column has values like 88+2 (class - character)

The desired result would be 90 (class - integer)

I tried to create a function in order to transform such multiple columns

```
add_fun <- function(x){
  a <- strsplit(x, "\\+")

  for (i in 1:length(a)){
    a[[i]] <- as.numeric(a[[i]])
  }

  for (i in 1:length(a)){
    a[[i]] <- a[[i]][1] + a[[i]][2]
  }

  x <- as.numeric(unlist(a))
}
```

This works perfectly fine when I manually transform each column but the function won't return the desired results. Can someone sort this out?

Comment: you forgot `return(x)` at the end of the function.

Comment: @JBGruber Thanks for the reply but it still doesn't work. The x part remains the same in the data frame

Comment: Can you post a sample data column.

Comment: Without any data or error message it is hard to say anything else. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/5028841) for some guidance.

Comment: I run your function and add `return(x)`, and it works on my computer.

Comment: Hi everyone
Thanks for your help. I've added the data source. The columns I want to transform are ST LS RS LW etc

Comment: The values remain unchanged for x despite that I have edited the function as x <- return(as.numeric(unlist(a))

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Just put `return(x)` under `x <- as.numeric(unlist(a))`.

Comment: Can you be clear what the "desired result" is? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show us how exactly you are calling this function. Functions return new values; they typically don't update values outside the function due to the scoping rules of functional programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

read the csv data in `df`
then extract the 4 columns required using

`dff <- df[, c("LS","ST", "RS","LW")]`

```
def_fun <- function(x){
  a <- strsplit(x, '\\+')
  for (i in length(a)){
    b <- sum(as.numeric(a[[i]]))
  }
  return (b)
}
```

Then apply the operations on the required columns

```
for (i in 1: ncol(dff)){
  dff[i] <- apply(dff[i], 1, FUN = def_fun)
}
```

You can `cbind` this dataFrame with the original one and drop the original columns.

I hope it proves helpful.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for. I think it must've been the scoping issue that was the hinderance